# Stream chrome tab to rtmp

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, flash, rtmp

I am running a website that contains clean HTML page with a flash player inside, this flash player is streaming a video.

I want to stream the entire html page outside to an RTMP server and keep it real-time, so the video will be played with the minimal possible latency after it has been forwarded.

Any ideas how to?

Comment: Which part of your question are you stuck on exactly? Tell us about your RTMP server. Does it allow transcoding of the input stream into another format? If yes, did you try encoding input (from tab) into a lower resolution (smaller file size)? That would reduce latency for slow connections.

Comment: Well, I am not sure how can I record the tab's content at all. Any clue?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any clues because I don't now what tools / knowledge you have access to. You're probably a Linux coder using Python, or maybe a Mac coder using Swift or Objective-C... I'm on Windows so I'd use C# to load the page into a container (form) within my app and "draw" snapshots of the form/page as bitmaps then send them to FFmpeg via Standard input/output to be encoded into some video format and also forwarded to my RTMP server. All this might be possible in your coding language and OS. Have you used FFmpeg? Does `std in/out` mean anything to you? See how it's un-Answerable at mo?

Comment: PS: If it's not important to _"stream the entire html page"_ and okay to just stream the video data only, I suggest you find the video input source of the Flash app that's playing the video. Check page source code or "Network Tools" in your browser and then set that video URL as input to your RTMP stream. (_eg:_ why record the TV/player when you can forward the original transmission itself to your RTMP server?).